# How do I create Pandas New Column Without Boolean Logic Error?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run code to create a new dataframe column with the value based on the row immediately below. I want to incorporate logic to test whether the row identity ('batter-pitcher' column) matches, and if it does update the new column based on the row below. For rows without a match, I would like to return 'na' or something along those lines. I tried the following code

```
full_count['batter-pitcher'] = full_count['batter'].astype(str) + "---" + full_count['pitcher'].astype(str)


full_count = full_count.loc[full_count['balls'] == 3]
full_count = full_count.loc[full_count['strikes'] == 2]


full_count['prior'] = full_count['batter-pitcher'].shift(periods=-1)
full_count['prior1'] = ['match' if full_count['prior'] == full_count['batter-pitcher'] else 'none']

full_count['prev_pitch'] = [full_count['description'].shift(periods=-1) if full_count['prior1'] == 'match' else "na"]
```

full_count is a dataframe and the last line, creating a 'prev_pitch' column, is intended to pull in a value from the row below if certain conditions are met. I keep receiving an

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
> in **nonzero**(self)    1327     1328     def **nonzero**(self):
> -> 1329         raise ValueError(    1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "    1331
> "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

error. I tried different means of defining 'prior1' e.g.

> full_count['prior1'] = full_count['prior'] == full_count['batter-pitcher']

but not with success. Any suggestions how to fix this code? Thank you!

[this is what the df looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rWmx.png) and for the prior1 Trues I would want them to pull the row below's 'description' column

```
    game_date   player_name batter  pitcher events  description balls   strikes des at_bat_number   pitch_number    batter-pitcher  prior   prior1
62  2021-10-31  Graveman, Kendall   501303  608665  field_out   hit_into_play   3   2   Ehire Adrianza lines out sharply to center fie...   81  6   501303---608665 608665---592767 False
4   2021-10-31  Smyly, Drew 608665  592767  strikeout   called_strike   3   2   Kendall Graveman called out on strikes. 79  6   608665---592767 592696---608665 False
186 2021-10-31  Graveman, Kendall   592696  608665  field_out   hit_into_play   3   2   Eddie Rosario flies out to center fielder Jose...   74  8   592696---608665 621020---664208 False
87  2021-10-31  Maton, Phil 621020  664208  strikeout   swinging_strike 3   2   Dansby Swanson strikes out swinging.    57  6   621020---664208 514888---455119 False
252 2021-10-31  Martin, Chris   514888  455119  strikeout   swinging_strike 3   2   Jose Altuve strikes out swinging.   47  6   514888---455119 624585---664353 False
171 2021-10-31  Urquidy, José   624585  664353  force_out   hit_into_play   3   2   Jorge Soler grounds into a force out, fielded ...   39  8   624585---664353 624585---664353 True
177 2021-10-31  Urquidy, José   624585  664353  NaN foul    3   2   Jorge Soler grounds into a force out, fielded ...   39  7   624585---664353 624585---664353 True
192 2021-10-31  Urquidy, José   624585  664353  NaN foul    3   2   Jorge Soler grounds into a force out, fielded ...   39  6   624585---664353 594807---554340 False
191 2021-10-31  García, Yimi    594807  554340  field_out   hit_into_play   3   2   Adam Duvall pops out to shortstop Carlos Correa.    31  12  594807---554340 594807---554340 True
198 2021-10-31  García, Yimi    594807  554340  NaN foul    3   2   Adam Duvall pops out to shortstop Carlos Correa.    31  11  594807---554340 594807---554340 True
```

Comment: please add a portion of your dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: Ok thanks, just added a screenshot. Really appreciate it! As for expected outputs, for all 'falses' in prior 1 (top few rows in screenshotted df) the new column should read 'na'. For index 171, it should pull in 'foul', index 177 'foul', and 191 'foul'.

Comment: screenshots don't help as we need to be able read the data easily to test your code and provide a solution. please post the data using something like df.head(10), or whichever slice of the dataframe makes sense. thanks.

Comment: Got it... added it above

Comment: try this: `full_count['prior1'] = np.where(full_count['prior'] == full_count['batter-pitcher'], 'match', 'none');full_count['prev_pitch'] = np.where(full_count['prior1'] == 'match', full_count['description'].shift(periods=-1) , "na")`

Answer (score 0):

You're not broadcasting the comparison correctly. One option is to do

```
full_count['prior1'] = full_count['prior'] == full_count['batter-pitcher']
```

This will create a boolean rather than string, but you seem to be using the string as a boolean anyway, so this makes things simpler. For the next line of code, you can do

```
full_count['prev_pitch'] = 
    full_count['description'].shift(periods=-1)*full_count['prior1']
```

This will put the value of `description` in any rows with a match, and an empty string otherwise (as long as `description` was a string; if it's a numeric, it'll put `0`).

Comment: Could something like this be used? It is not working, but I would've thought that if statements could get the same result...full_count['prev_pitch'] = full_count['description'].shift(periods=-1) if full_count['prior1'] == True

Comment: I also tried ` is True` instead of `== True` and had been using your `full_count['prior1'] = full_count['prior'] == full_count['batter-pitcher']` boolean creator code. It seems to be an issue with the Boolean column